# How to exclude Material styles with Angular encapsulation Shadow DOM

Tags: angular

I have an angular library that uses *Angular Material* components, in-which I created an `app-alert` component to display some important informations. I've copied some *Bootstrap* styles that deal with modals and insert them inside the component styles file `alert.component.css`.

I want this component style to be isolated from the app so I choose ***Shadow DOM encapsulation*** for the job.

Here's the component annotation

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { AppIcon } from '../icons/icon.component';
import { AppButton } from '../buttons/button.component';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-alert',
  templateUrl: './alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alert.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule, AppIcon, AppButton],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppAlert {
...
}
```

Yet on the browser's DevTools I see a lot of unwanted styles from *Angular Material* like mat-form-fiels, mat-expansion-panel, ...

I think it's some how baked with the component, even though Im not importing any MatComponent nor does the `AppIcon` and `AppButton`
How can I fix this?